# Using flask with joblib

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing

While using flask, I came accross an issue where I could not spawn parallel jobs with joblib. I get a message :

> UserWarning: Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1

Is there a way to get joblib to actually run more than 1 job at a time when executed from within flask?

Edit: I found https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180 which says joblib cannot support nested parallelism. I am also willing to swap it out for another library if it can work maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i used to run the app flask with :

```
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", threaded=True)
```

Then I tested with threaded=False (because joblib wants to be in the main thread), but it didn't worked too. I don't know why, but it works with debug=False...

Here is how i fixed the problem :

```
app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0", threaded=False)
```

If someone knows why the debug=True causes joblib warning, i'd like to know :)

Comment: That probably just disables warn-level error reports rather than actually allowing higher n_jobs values